# Function in Scheme that checks whether the length of a list is even

Tags: scheme, racket

Hi I have edited the code for function in scheme that checks whether the length of a list is even.

```
(define even-length?
  (lambda (l)
  (cond 
   ((null? l)#f)
   ((equal? (remainder (length(l)) 2) 0) #t)
   (else #f))))
```

Is it corrrect?

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have the syntax for `if` and `cond` all mixed up.  I suggest referring to the [language reference](http://docs.plt-scheme.org/reference/if.html).  `if` only has two clauses, and you don't write `else` for the else clause.  (Hint:  You shouldn't need an `if` for this function at all.)

Also, consider whether it makes sense to return `null` if the list is `null`; probably you want to return `#t` or `#f` instead.

Oh yeah, and rewrite your call of `length` to be a proper prefix-style Scheme function call.

Comment: Closer, but `length(l)` is not the way to call a function in Scheme, and it could be much simpler; think of how to write the same thing without the `cond`.

Comment: @mquander Hi I am not able to write the function without cond.Can you help me?

Comment: OK, what I was getting at was something like Jerry's suggestion.  You've suffered enough, so I'll just give some code:  `(define even-length? (lambda (l) (equal? (remainder (length l) 2))))`  This code works because `equal?` already returns `#t` or `#f`, which is what you want from your function anyway.

Comment: I missed putting the zero in that function in my comment, but I'm sure you can fill it in.

Answer (score 2):

The code is clearly wrong -- your `%2` assuming infix notation, where Scheme uses prefix notation. The syntax of your `if` is wrong as well -- for an `if`, the `else` is implicit (i.e. you have `if condition true-expression false-expression`. In this case, you're trying to return #t from one leg and #f from another leg -- that's quite unnecessary. You can just return the expression that you tested in the `if`.

Edit: one other detail -- you should really rename this to something like `even-length?`. Even if I assume that it's a predicate, a name like `even` would imply to me that `(even 3)` should return `#f`, and `(even 4)` should return `#t` -- but in this case, neither works at all.

Edit2: Since mquander already gave you one version of the code, I guess one more won't hurt. I'd write it like:

```
(define (even-length? L) (even? (length L)))
```

I don't like using lower-case 'l' (but itself) much, so I've capitalized it. Since `even?` is built in, I've used that instead of finding the remainder.

Running this produces:

```
> (even-length? `(1 2 3))
#f
> (even-length? `(1 2 3 4))
#t
>
```

This is different from what you had in one respect: the length of an empty list is 0, which is considered an even number, so:

(even-length? `())

gives #t.

Comment: @nan:No -- '%' is used in C and related languages. Scheme normally calls it 'remainder'.

Comment: Hi Jerry
Thanks for your help.
Is there  any other simple function in scheme that checks whether the length of list is even.
Now I have edited the code also.

Comment: Offhand, I don't know of a built-in function to check whether the length of a list is even -- but there is a built-in function to check whether a number is even, which might be helpful. As mquander already pointed out, your call of `length` isn't syntactically correct yet either...

Answer (score 1):

```
(define even-length? (lambda (l)
    (even? (length l))))
```

Usage:

```
(even-length? '(1 2 3 4))
#t
(even-length? '(1 2 3 ))
#f
```

As others pointed out, there is indeed a predicate to check evenness of a number, so why not using it?

EDIT: I just saw Jerry Coffin wrote the same function witht the same example... Sorry for repeating :-)